# Exclamation marks in bash command arguments

Tags: bash, arguments

If I type the following command in Bash:

```
echo "dog!!"
```

I don't get the string `dog!!`. Instead I get something else.

I tried to echo the string `"dog!!"` by echoing `"dog\!\!`, but it doesn’t work either.

How can I use command arguments when there are two exclamation marks?

I want these exclamation marks to be treated as exclamation marks without any special function.

Two exclamation marks `"!!"` seem to be the last command.

Comment: By the way, if you try `echo "dog\!\!"` in this online RHEL terminal seems to work fine : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: Is it possible you are not using `bash`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to either escape the exclamation marks, or use **single** quotes:

```
echo dog\!\!
echo 'dog!!'
```

(This doesn’t explain why your `echo "dog\!\!"` doesn’t work, but it should work, I don’t know why it wouldn’t. Or at least, it shouldn’t act on the history; in Bash it will output `dog\!\!`.)

Comment: Thanks. Single quotes seems to work. Escaping the exclamation marks does not work inside double quotes.

Comment: On Bash 4.3.30, `echo "\!"` prints `\!`, i.e. the backslash stays, so it doesn't work too well as an escape.

Comment: @ilkkachu that’s what I’m seeing too.

Comment: @StephenKitt What version of Bash are you using? Please include this in your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In Bash, if you want the exclamation marks to be always treated as regular characters and don't need history expansion, you can disable it for the current shell with

```
set +o histexpand
```

Or add the command to the [usual configuration files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), i.e. most likely `.bashrc` to disable it for all shells.

Comment: @StephenKitt OK, I didn't read well obviously. He might have included information about where do I specify this option for it to be set generally for all scripts. Very well, we did a good job on taking this apart :)

Comment: @Vlastimil, I think I missed some comments, but I added a note about the usual configuration files. (Bash's logic of which configuration files to read in which situations is a bit odd in my opinion, but it's not the main point here.)

Answer (score 1):

On **Linux Mint 18.1** based on Ubuntu 16.04 with:

```
bash --version | head -1
```

> ```
> GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
> ```

The behavior is as follows:

```
echo dog\!\!
```

results in:

> ```
> dog!!
> ```

```
echo 'dog!!'
```

results in:

> ```
> dog!!
> ```

```
echo "dog!!"
```

prints unexpectedly the *dog* followed by the last command; e.g. if you did `ls` before, it prints:

> ```
> echo "dogls"
> dogls
> ```

---

On **GNU/Linux Debian 9 Stretch** there is a slightly newer version:

```
bash --version | head -1
```

> ```
> GNU bash, version 4.4.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
> ```

The behavior is as follows:

```
echo dog\!\!
```

results in:

> ```
> dog!!
> ```

```
echo 'dog!!'
```

results in:

> ```
> dog!!
> ```

```
echo "dog!!"
```

prints unexpectedly the *dog* followed by the last command; e.g. if you did `ls` before, it prints:

> ```
> echo "dogls"
> dogls
> ```

---

It seems consistent to me.

It may be possible that on old systems with older version of `bash` it behaves slightly different. But on new systems, we can expect this behavior.

Comment: Strings in single quotes aren’t expanded, strings in double quotes are, so it’s normal for the history operators to be processed in double quotes.